# Need graphics configuration for 12.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, hardware

I am trying to get the graphic interface running for a new 12.04 install on an embedded PC.
There is no separate graphic card but the onboard graphic chip is an SM722.  Is there a driver in ubuntu for this chip? Is there anywhere else I can find this driver?  My web searches have turned up empty.

If there is support for this chip in 12.04 how do I tell the OS about this chip? Is there an option at boot time?

Comment: There should be support for it in linux in general.  My searching turned up this bug from about a year ago: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=556779 ... not Ubuntu but it tells me there's OSS running that chipset

Comment: This is a Silicon Motion *Lynx 3DM+* controller, FYI, if you want to google more.

Comment: Kept googling and I see that there are major bugs with it recently, but it works with vesa in arch https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=548974

Comment: OP has not signed on in 5+ years and never responded to @RobotHumans comment posted before last OP signon. 12.04 is EOL and there are no answers to this question. VTC as `not reproducible`.